# Is it possible to get a list of commit comments via the Azure devops API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When viewing a commit in the web interface for an Azure Devops repo, it's possible to leave a comment on a commit by clicking to the left of a specific line and typing something in the box that appears. I'm building a tool that takes various analytics of remote repositories, including the frequency and volume of feedback on commits. Being able to get this information (or at least a summary of it, like a comment count per commit) would be excellent. Is it possible to get a list of such comments?

Such information definitely exists for pull requests, [via this API method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20threads/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). PR comments and commit comments have a very similar interface, and I can confirm the PR method to be working, but have had no such luck finding an equivalent method for commits themselves. I've tried scanning the documentation, to no avail, as well as interrogating the output of various things like file diffs and commit info, which also don't contain the commit comments.

Does such functionality exist within the Azure Devops API in any form?

Comment: Check #1 if you want to get the initial comment for one specific commit. (We only have one initial comment per commit). Check #2 if you want to get the added comments(considered as content in discussion by Devops) for one commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does such functionality exist within the Azure Devops API in any form?

1.We can use [Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to retrieve all available git commits for one specific repo:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.1
```

Also we can use [Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to retrieve a particular commit:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=5.1
```

Both them can give you the comments for corresponding commits.

[image]

**Note:**

The comment here indicates the **initial comment** for one commit, see:

[image]

2.If you're trying to get the comments created with this button:

[image]

The comments here are different things from the initial comments. We call them content in discussion... And here's one **undocumented** api you can use:

Replace the {OrganizationName},{ProjectID},{RepostoryID} and {CommitID} with your own values, it should work to get the comments in the discussion.

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/discussion/Threads?artifactUri=vstfs%3A%2F%2F%2FGit%2FCommit%2F{ProjectID}%252F{RepositoryID}%252F{CommitId}&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

1). My comments(not initial comment):

[image]

2). My url:

[image]

3). Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**In addition:**

1.Get ProjectID by name:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectName}?api-version=5.1)
```

2.Get RepoID by name:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}?api-version=5.1
```

3.We can easily get the `commitID` in web portal UI with the Copy Full SHA button. Or use [commits-related api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).